# sinatra-r18n: How do I get date in a specific language?

Tags: internationalization, sinatra

That's basically it. As far as I can tell, `sinatra` inspects such places like `Accept-Language` HTTP header, `:locale` URL parameter, `:locale` session variable in an attempt to detect user's preferred language. But what if I just want to get it in the language I want?

**UPD**

Consider the following code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/r18n'
get '/' do
    l Date.today, '%B'
end
```

It outputs `February` for me. How do I make it output the month in German or any other language regardless of what `sinatra` thinks is appropriate for user?

Comment: Get what exactly? What's the problem?

Comment: I want to do things like `l Time.now, 'de'` or `R18n.set_lang 'de'; l Time.now` or `R18n.change_lang('de') { l Time.now }`.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect on what you already tried, what was the expected output and what you got instead. My guess would be that you tried `Time.strftime` which ignores the locale, and you'll probably need to use a gem such as [r18n](https://github.com/ai/r18n#flexible-locales).